# MFC C++ CButton mouse hover event

Tags: c++, mfc

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg, CDialogEx)

    ON_WM_TIMER()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_DRAWITEM()
    ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
    ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()



    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON1, &CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnBnClickedTestButton)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_CHECK1, &CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnBnClickedTestCheckbox)

    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDOK, &CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnBnClickedOk)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_CUSTOMDRAW, IDC_SLIDER1, &CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnNMCustomdrawSlider1)

    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON3, &CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnBnClickedButton3)
    ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BUTTON2, &CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnBnClickedButton2)
 
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE() // I HAVE ADDED THIS
 

END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{

    CRect rect;
    CButton* pButton = static_cast<CButton*>(GetDlgItem(IDC_BUTTON1)); // Replace IDC_MY_BUTTON with your button's ID

    // Check if the mouse is over the button
    if (pButton != nullptr && pButton->GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr) {
        pButton->GetClientRect(&rect);
        pButton->ScreenToClient(&point);

        if (rect.PtInRect(point)) {
            // Change the button's color when the mouse hovers over it
            int i = 10;
            pButton->Invalidate();
        }
        else {
            // Revert to the default color when the mouse leaves
            int i = 20;
            pButton->Invalidate();
        }
    }
 
    CDialogEx::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}
```

My breakpoint should come at `int i = 10;` but it always went to `int i = 20;` even my mouse on IDC_BUTTON1. Can someone please help how to change the button border on the mouse hover? I am new to MFC C++

Comment: The passed `point` will be in client coordinates of the dialog window, not screen coordinates. As you're working with the button's own client rect, you will need to convert the point to screen coordinates first, using the dialog's `ClientToScreen`.

Comment: The area of the button is reported by a call to `GetWindowRect`. However, I believe that `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages are delivered to the window under the mouse cursor, i.e., the button control (not the dialog that implements the `OnMouseMove` handler). If that is true you'd need to subclass the button control and implement the logic there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
    ...
    // Check if the mouse is over the button
    if (pButton != nullptr && pButton->GetSafeHwnd() != nullptr) {
        // pButton->EnableWindow(false);
        pButton->GetWindowRect(&rect);  // get button rectangle
        ScreenToClient(rect);           // convert it to coordinates relative 
                                        // to dialog client rectangle

        // point is already relative to the dialog's client rectangle
        TRACE("%d, %d\n", point.x, point.y);

        if (rect.PtInRect(point)) {
            // Change the button's color when the mouse hovers over it
            int i = 10;
            pButton->Invalidate();
        }
        else {
            // Revert to the default color when the mouse leaves
            int i = 20;
            pButton->Invalidate();
        }
    }
    ...
```

But there is another problem: `OnMouseMove` will only be called if the mouse pointer is not on a clickable control because the mouse move event is delivered to the window below the mouse cursor (be aware that a button *is* a window). You can check this by looking at the debug output, where `TRACE`s will be shown.

If you uncomment `pButton->EnableWindow(false);` the button becomes disabled and mouse move events will be delivered to the dialog window (and not more to the button) even if you hover over the button. **This is not really helpful, it's just for demonstration.**

The real answer you're looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77438790/898348).

Comment: Thank you :) this works for me pButton->EnableWindow(false). this was the issue.

Comment: BTW: you are aware that the two `int i = 10;` and `int i = 12;` don't have any effect.

Comment: @user2951849 *"this was the issue."* - No, it wasn't. Disabling a window just means that the window no longer responds to user input, and input messages bubble up to the parent. The *real* issue is that you need to handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages *in the button control* itself.

Comment: `pButton->EnableWindow(false)` is pointless. I only added it for demonstration purposes in order to show you that the mouse move messages are not handled by the dialog as long as the control is not disabled.

Comment: But that demonstrates something that's not relevant. Once you handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages in the button control you never even have to check whether the mouse is inside the button. It will only receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages if the mouse *is* inside the window rectangle. The system already performed the check for you.

Comment: @IInspectable I think the OP's actual question is: _"How can I change the color of a button when the mouse cursor hovers over it"_. It's an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 2):

As was covered in other answers, there's a bug in the code that attempts to determine whether the mouse pointer is inside a button control. It retrieves the button's client size (in client coordinates) and subsequently interprets those coordinates as screen coordinates. The result of the calculation is deterministic yet meaningless.

---

However, that is a [Red Herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring), distracting from the core issue: Mouse input is always<sup>1</sup> delivered to the window under the mouse cursor. As the mouse cursor moves across the button, [`WM_MOUSEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mousemove) messages are posted to the button window. Its parent (the dialog) will not receive `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages as long as the mouse cursor is inside a child window.

It is thus necessary to handle `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages in the button control. The system allows client code to modify standard behavior of a control through a technique called [subclassing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).

Subclassing is an involved topic, but MFC provides powerful tools that make it much more convenient to employ<sup>2</sup>.

## The Tools

Subclassing controls with MFC requires the following steps:

1. Define a class deriving from the respective MFC control wrapper<sup>3</sup>.
2. Instantiate an object of this class by declaring a class member in its parent dialog.
3. Wire up message routing.
4. Customize button behavior.

### Deriving a custom class

Deriving a custom class is as simple as typing `class CMyButton : public CButton {};`. However, message routing requires a bit more infrastructure (namely, a message map), and instead of typing that out ourselves we'll have the *Add New Item* wizard do it for us:

- Select *Project* → *Add New Item...*.
- This opens a dialog with a search box in the top right corner. Upon entering the search term `mfc class` the filtered list contains an item named *MFC Class*. Select it and click *Add*.
- This opens the *Add MFC Class* dialog where we can enter an arbitrary *Class name* (such as `CMyButton`) as well as the *Base class* (`CButton`). Hitting *OK* finally creates the following files:

*CMyButton.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

class CMyButton : public CButton
{
public:
    CMyButton();
    virtual ~CMyButton();

protected:
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

*CMyButton.cpp*

```cpp
#include "pch.h"

#include "CMyButton.h"


CMyButton::CMyButton() {}
CMyButton::~CMyButton() {}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyButton, CButton)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I've removed the `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` and `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` macros since we don't need MFC's run-time type information support here<sup>4</sup>.

### Instantiating the `CMyButton` class

With the `CMyButton` class defined, we have to instantiate it whenever needed. The most convenient way to do this is by declaring it as a (`private`) class member of the dialog class that uses it:

```cpp
#include "CMyButton.h"

class CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg : public CDialogEx {
    // ...
private:
    CMyButton m_MyButton;
}
```

Doing this ties the lifetime of `m_MyButton` to that of its parent dialog. It gets constructed alongside the dialog and is automatically destroyed when the dialog is.

### Wiring up message routing

So far we've created a "custom" button control whose lifetime coincides with that of its parent dialog. However, button messages still go through the standard button control implementation. To route them through `CMyButton`'s message map, the native button control needs to be associated with the `CMyButton` class.

This is done with a call to [`DDX_Control`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/standard-dialog-data-exchange-routines#ddx_control) in the dialog's [`DoDataExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#dodataexchange) override (see [Dialog Data Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange) for more details):

```cpp
#include "resource.h"

void CPQVDirect2DControlsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX)
{
    // ...
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_BUTTON1, m_MyButton);
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
}
```

Doing this chains `CMyButton`'s message map ahead of default button message handling, allowing the C++ implementation to augment or override default processing.

### Customizing behavior

At this point everything is set up and `CMyButton` has agency over just about any aspect controlling the look and feel of the native control it is associated with. Indeed, the code emitted by the [message map macros](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/message-map-macros-mfc) is already being executed, even if inconsequential. Let's quickly change that by hooking up a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message handler.

*CMyButton.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

class CMyButton : public CButton
{
    // ...
private:
    void OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point);
};
```

*CMyButton.cpp*

```cpp
void CMyButton::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point) {
    ::OutputDebugStringW(L"Hit\n");
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyButton, CButton)
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Running this under a debugger will display `Hit` in the debugger [output window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/output-window) whenever the mouse moves across our `CMyButton` control. That's a step forward, but the problem isn't solved just yet.

Recall that mouse messages are delivered to the window under the mouse cursor only. Since the implementation above is concerned with the button control alone, this relaxed our obligation to double-check whether the mouse is inside the control. Albeit, it introduced a new problem: How do we know when the mouse has moved **out** of our control?

To resolve this we need to reach out to the system: It can post a [`WM_MOUSELEAVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-mouseleave) message whenever that happens. But things aren't as simple as dropping an `ON_WM_MOUSELEAVE()` into our message map and being done with it. We have to proactively request mouse tracking by calling into [`TrackMouseEvent`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackmouseevent). Complexity doesn't end here. `WM_MOUSELEAVE` is a one-shot notification, where the tracking request is canceled once the message is generated. We have to re-request tracking whenever the mouse enters our control. And while [there is no `WM_MOUSEENTER` message](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031013-00/?p=42193) we also have to internally record state information.

That's a fair bit of information to digest. Luckily, the implementation is not nearly as intimidating as the explanations leading up to it. Following is the next iteration:

*CMyButton.h*

```cpp
#pragma once

class CMyButton : public CButton
{
    // ...
private:
    // ...
    void OnMouseLeave();

    // State tracking
    bool m_IsMouseInside = false;
};
```

*CMyButton.cpp*

```cpp
void CMyButton::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    if (!m_IsMouseInside)
    {
        ::OutputDebugStringW(L"WM_MOUSEENTER\n");

        // Request mouse tracking
        auto tme = TRACKMOUSEEVENT { sizeof(TRACKMOUSEEVENT), TME_LEAVE, m_hWnd, 0 };
        ::TrackMouseEvent(&tme);

        // Update state
        m_IsMouseInside = true;
    }
}

void CMyButton::OnMouseLeave()
{
    ::OutputDebugStringW(L"WM_MOUSELEAVE\n");

    // Update state
    m_IsMouseInside = false;
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyButton, CButton)
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE()
    ON_WM_MOUSELEAVE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

That wasn't too bad. The code is still fairly compact and its intent can be inferred from skimming over it. This was surprisingly easy to pull off.

Suspiciously easy.

Indeed, there's a regression. The default hover highlight is gone from a button whose behavior is redirected through `CMyButton`'s implementation ([enabling visual styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview) makes this easy to observe).

This defect wasn't introduced just now. It started materializing as we began customizing the behavior by opting into handling `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages way up in the very first iteration. The `OnMouseMove` handler doesn't do much. The crucial detail isn't in what it does. It is in what it *doesn't* do: Namely, getting the default implementation caught up. With MFC subclass chains are represented as class hierarchies. To get the default implementation back into the loop we need to call into the base class:

*CMyButton.h*

```cpp
using BaseClass = CButton;

class CMyButton : public BaseClass
{
    // ...
};
```

*CMyButton.cpp*

```cpp
void CMyButton::OnMouseMove(UINT nFlags, CPoint point)
{
    // ...

    BaseClass::OnMouseMove(nFlags, point);
}

void CMyButton::OnMouseLeave()
{
    // ...

    BaseClass::OnMouseLeave();
}


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyButton, BaseClass)
    // ...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

I went ahead and introduced the `BaseClass` type alias. Should we ever decide to derive `CMyButton` from a different class then all that's needed is a change to a single line of code.

---

<sup>1</sup> *Unless that window is disabled (see [`EnableWindow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow)), or mouse input is captured by a different window (see [`SetCapture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setcapture)).*

<sup>2</sup> *The subject remains complex, and the tools cannot acquit a user of the necessity to apprehend its internals and intricacies.*

<sup>3</sup> *The following derives from [`CButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cbutton-class) for illustration only. [`CMFCButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cmfcbutton-class) is a better fit as it already provides the customization points we're implementing manually.*

<sup>4</sup> *In hindsight I should have just added the `.h`/`.cpp` files and jotted this down manually.*

Answer (score 1):

As many have noted, `OnMouseMove()` passes a point in dialog client coordinates. Don't call `GetClientRect()` for the button, it makes no sense because the top-left point is always (0,0) - this function basically returns the control's client area size. Instead call `GetWindowRect()` for the button, which returns the window's rect in screen coordinates. Then of course you will have to either convert them to dialog client coordinates, or convert the `point`'s client coordinates to screen, before checking if the point lies in the button's rect.

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer.

This should work:

```
CRect winRect;
this->GetClientRect(&winRect); // get client rect of window

CRect buttonRect;
pButton->GetClientRect(&buttonRect);


// I believe this cast is safe
pButton->MapWindowPoints(this, (LPPOINT)&buttonRect, 2);


// buttonRect is now in client window coordinates
bool isPointOnButton = buttonRect.PtInRect(point);
```

Comment: Actually, the OP uses client coordinates of the button for the rect, so they would need to convert the point to screen coordinates first, then convert to the button's client coords.

Comment: ahhh...  Then the OP just needs to call MapWindowPoints.

Comment: Thanks! but no luck. Still gives the same result. please check  https://ibb.co/489Vp7F for screenshot. @AdrianMole